# Webstorm retain Find menu between editors

Tags: find, webstorm

I am new to webstorm and can't find how to change this setting.  Basically the problem is when I highlight text, hit Ctrl-F to find that text and then switch between open files, the Find toolbar vanishes.  Is there a way to retain the find toolbar across all opened files?

Comment: Nope -- that panel is per editor tab. Unfortunately I cannot find that ticket right now that asks for "global" behaviour -- my search-fu is not that strong, apparently.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Thank you.  Hopefully this "feature" will be added soon.